# Amazon EC2 cannot connect SSH via Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Target machine is ubuntu, already set inbound rule for ssh at port 22 for all IPs(0.0.0.0/0). Result of `ssh -v -v -i ladc2015.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-183-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` is:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-183-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.183.128.207] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.183.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-183-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Already tried using public IP instead public DNS, already tested making all traffic inbound rule with all IPs, already used `root`, `ubuntu` instead of `ec2-user` as username. Still cannot connect. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Try the username `admin`.

Comment: @Pierre-Jean same result

Comment: Can you try to add your own ssh key to AWS / this instance?

Comment: @Pierre-Jean I have no idea how to do that, but I guess not. AWS is my client's and the development code is not on my place, I just have access to its console and restore some backups. I have done those steps but I need to restart httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the 2200 port instead?

```
ssh -v -v -i ladc2015.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-183-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -p 2200
```

This may work if SSH on the EC2 instance is not correctly set to port 22.